# How to properly nest Bash backticks

Tags: bash, shell, unix, quoting

Either I missed some backlash or backlashing does not seem to work with too much programmer-quote-looping.

```
$ echo "hello1-`echo hello2-\`echo hello3-\`echo hello4\`\``"

hello1-hello2-hello3-echo hello4
```

**Wanted**

```
hello1-hello2-hello3-hello4-hello5-hello6-...
```

Comment: The question should probably read "How to use Bash backticks recursively".  That should help the Googlers out there.

Comment: what is it that you are trying to do.? this has no meaning at all.

Comment: @joey, title changed, ure welcome :D

Comment: Oops, scratch that.  It should read "How do I nest backticks in bash?" .  I got recursion and nesting mixed up.

Comment: Backticks are `deprecated`, therefore use `$(cmd)`.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Use `$(commands)` instead:

```
$ echo "hello1-$(echo hello2-$(echo hello3-$(echo hello4)))"
hello1-hello2-hello3-hello4
```

`$(commands)` does the same thing as backticks, but you can nest them.

You may also be interested in Bash range expansions:

```
echo hello{1..10}
hello1 hello2 hello3 hello4 hello5 hello6 hello7 hello8 hello9 hello10
```

Comment: +1 like the {1..10}. Limit it with array? ZSH can "${$( date )[2,4]}". Why not: "echo ${echo hello1-$(echo hello2)[1]}"?

Comment: not all shells support `$()`

Comment: @CervEd Just curious, what system and shell were you using?  On Ubuntu, even the default "sh" (dash) supports the dollar notation and nesting it.

Comment: @JoeyAdams I use shells that support `$()` and AFAIK most shells support it, but not all. [Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/sh-1.html#scrolltoc) `sh` doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 38):

if you insist to use backticks, following could be done

```
$ echo "hello1-`echo hello2-\`echo hello3-\\\`echo hello4\\\`\``"
```

you have to put backslashes, `\\ \\\\ \\\\\\\\` by 2x and so on, its just very ugly, use `$(commands)` as other suggested.

Answer (score 12):

Any time you want to evaluate a command use `command substitution`:

```
$(command)
```

Any time you want to evaluate an arithmetic expression use `expression substitution`:

```
$((expr))
```

You can nest these like this:

Let's say file1.txt is 30 lines long and file2.txt is 10 lines long, than you can evaluate an expression like this:

```
$(( $(wc -l file1.txt) - $(wc -l file2.txt) ))
```

which would output 20 ( the difference in number of lines between two files).

Answer (score 10):

It's a lot easier if you use bash's `$(cmd)` [command substitution syntax](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_30.html), which is much more friendly to being nested:

```
$ echo "hello1-$(echo hello2-$(echo hello3-$(echo hello4)))"
hello1-hello2-hello3-hello4
```

Comment: This is not restricted to *bash*. It is available in all shells that conform to POSIX 1003.1 (“POSIX shells”) and most Bourne-derived shell (*ksh*, *ash*, *dash*, *bash*, *zsh*, etc.) though not the actual Bourne shell (i.e. http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html ).

Comment: wow, timestamp on this answer is IDENTICAL to that on @joey_adams answer! Synchronisity in it's most literal meaning :)  Upvoting here too (:

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes backtick nesting can be substituted with `xargs` and pipes

```
$ echo hello4 | xargs echo hello3 | xargs echo hello2 | xargs echo hello1
hello1 hello2 hello3 hello4
```

Drawback of this solution are:

- All arguments must be provided in reverse order (4→1);
- All arguments become space separated (solvable with `tr`):

  ```
  $ echo hello4 | xargs echo hello3 | xargs echo hello2 | xargs echo hello1 | tr ' ' '-'
  hello1-hello2-hello3-hello4
  ```

---

Let's show a real use-case.

Following commands work in bash, but not in tcsh (backtick nesting is not handled very good in tcsh)

```
$ ls $(dirname $(which bash))
$ ls `dirname \`which bash\``
```

They can be substituted with

```
$ which bash | xargs dirname | xargs ls
```

Comment: This `xargs` workaround is very handy when you're stuck with `sh` such as in a Makefile commands.

Answer (score -1):

You can capture and combine into a variable incrementally

```sh
__=`printf hello2-`
__=`printf "${__}hello3-"`
__=`printf "${__}hello4-"`
printf "hello1-${__}"
```