# Running sh commands in Jenkins Pipeline with escaping quotes

Tags: shell, awk, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am running a shell script within the Jenkins pipeline and i want to print into a text file latest files names column  created by date, i dont want want to print time & date column etc, just anything after 9 which are files names  and print to into a txt file..

codes are as below:

Note: when i run those commands in bash all work fine,  \ is added as Jenkins does not seems to like the $ without the dollar sign all run fine in shell.

out put in shell is like this:

```
 bash.sh
        home
        testfile.txt
        blabla.csv
        rtyuioiuytrty.xml
```

like above I would like to be printed in Jenkinsfile. Jenkins does not seem to like to run those codes as below: I also tried this loop

```
node ('node') {
    stage ('SSH To server') {
      sshagent(credentials: ['sshkey']) {
        script {
        sh"""ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@servername << EOF

      if [ \$? -ne 0 ]; then
                    echo " Error while connecting SSH "
                    exit 1
            fi  

     cd ${SOURCE_PATH}
     if [ \$? -ne 0 ]; then
           echo "Error while doing change directory \${SOURCE_PATH} "
           exit 1
     fi

     ls -lrt | grep "$(date '+%b %e')" |awk '{ s =""; for (i = 9; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print }'


        exit
        EOF
   """
```

Comment: This seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484213/using-nested-command-substitution-in-jenkins-pipeline-sh-step but it would be good to see how exactly you are putting this in on the Jenkins side. Is this in a Groovy script or in a dialog box in the Jenkins web UI somewhere?

Comment: I am doing like this : sh '''' ssh name@server << EOF bash script here, and then '''EOF

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show this with proper code formatting and more context.

Comment: Instead of """ (3 double quotes) you can use ''' (3 single quotes). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761498/whats-the-difference-of-strings-within-single-or-double-quotes-in-groovy

Comment: Multiline shell scripts should not really be inlined into Jenkins Pipeline for this and other reasons. Consider converting this to Groovy, or at worst just putting it in a script and executing the script.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the hell of escaping in Jenkins :-)

probably the below command will help you

```
node(''){
  sh "touch test.txt"
  sh """ls -lrt | grep \"\$(date '+%b %e')\" |awk '{ s =\"\"; for (i = 9; i <= NF; i++) s = s \$i \" \"; print s }'"""
}
```

The gist is, you will have to escape double quotes and the dollar.

Answer for your updated code snippet is

```
 sh"""ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@servername << EOF
        if [ \$? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo \" Error while connecting SSH \"
            exit 1
        fi  
        cd \${SOURCE_PATH}
        if [ \$? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo \"Error while doing change directory \${SOURCE_PATH} \"
            exit 1
        fi
        ls -lrt | grep \"\$(date '+%b %e')\" | awk '{ print \\\$9}'
        exit
        EOF
    """
```

Comment: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 36: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 36, column 20.
      sh """ls -lrt | grep "$(date '+%b %e')" |awk '{ s =""; for (i = 9; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print }'""

Comment: The above code snippet that I posted echos `test.txt` in my case.  Did you execute the exact code snippet and got the error? Could you provide your updated command ?

Comment: ```Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on agent01 in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/sandbox-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ touch test.txt
[Pipeline] sh
+ ls -lrt
+ date +%b %e
+ grep Jul 17
+ awk { s =""; for (i = 9; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print s }
test.txt 
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS```

Comment: node ('Node') {
        stage ('SSH To server') {
          sshagent(credentials: ['sshkey]) {
            script {
            sh"""ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server << EOF

Comment: if [ \$? -ne 0 ]; then
                        echo " Error while connecting SSH "
                        exit 1
             fi  
  
   cd ${SOURCE_PATH}
   if [ \$? -ne 0 ]; then
                        echo "Error while doing change directory \${SOURCE_PATH} "
                        exit 1
                        fi
    
   ls -lrt | grep "$(date '+%b %e')" |awk '{ s =""; for (i = 9; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print }'
   
    
            exit
            EOF""

Comment: sorry i cant add it properly here,, i need to add those codes above maybe so you can seeit how i am running

Comment: Could you please update your question with this script? It’s hard to read here

Comment: Thanks Ram,   iupdated the question not to sure you can see it

Comment: Thanks again Sham, still the awk did not print just the files names i am after, printed date and time.. sounds like did not work awk

Comment: U were right. The awk was not printing the 9th field. It wasn't escaped properly. I have updated the answer, basically, you have to use three escape characters. `\\\$9`

Comment: You deserve more upvotes for the accurate "hell of escaping in Jenkins" comment alone. :)