# Need advice for using nested command subsitution

Tags: linux, redhat

I'm trying to wrap my head around nested command substitution. I tried nesting backticks but obviously that doesn't work.  How would you nest the following without declaring the ${host} variable first?

```
host=$(hostname|cut -c1-14);for id in `aladmin list|grep ${host}|awk '{print $2}'`;do aladmin delete ${id};done
```

The command lists all alarms on a server, greps for the first 14 characters of the hostname and then deletes the alarm with the alarm ID found in field 2 by awk.

My question does in no way duplicate the 'hello' in previous post:
[How to properly nest Bash backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657012/how-to-properly-nest-bash-backticks)

Thanks in advance,
Bjoern

Comment: `grep ... | awk` is an anti-pattern

Answer (score 0):

Do everything in awk.  There's no need to use the for loop and the grep, etc.  There are better ways than this, but as a first approximation, try something like:

```
aladmin list | awk "/$(hostname | cut -c1-14)/"'{ print "aladmin delete " $2 | "sh"}'
```

Comment: You could probably remove the need for cut through using awk's substr as well.

Comment: Yes, that winds up looking something like: `awk '$0 ~ substr(h, 1, 14){ print "aladmin delete " $2 | "sh"}' h=$(hostname)`